# "State Database error: Expected pruning mode: constrained" when running sync for RMRK

Tags: substrate, polkadot

RMRK [Syncing doc](https://docs.rmrk.app/syncing) advises to start kusama node with

```
chmod +x polkadot && mv polkadot kusama
./kusama --pruning archive --db rocksdb
```

When i run this in Linux, it says "State Database error: Expected pruning mode: constrained".  The same occurs when i run rust-compiled directly on Mac.  any ideas about this errror message and how to get past it?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to run kusama from a snapshot. And got same error.

For me solution was to add this:

```
--unsafe-pruning --pruning=1000
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Note: If you downloaded the database you need to match the pruning params.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you started your chain without archive pruning in the past, so dbs don't match. Purge chain and try again.

```
./kusama purge-chain
```